# Calling a function is calling another one also

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have two buttons:

[image: two buttons]

The one on the right calls a function named `update()`:

```
 <script>
 function update(buttonid){
   document.getElementById(buttonid).disabled = true;

   event.stopPropagation();

   var textboxid = buttonid.slice(0, -2);
   var id= textboxid.substr(0, textboxid.indexOf('_'));
   var columnid= textboxid.substr(textboxid.indexOf('_')+1, textboxid.length);
   var value=document.getElementById(textboxid).value;

   var str=textboxid+"_"+value;


   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
     // code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.open("GET","ListaRyF/Update?q="+str,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }
 </script>
```

The button on the left calls a function named 'row_update()', which is still empty.

The problem is that when I click the left button, also calls the function of the right button.

the HTML code of the button is the following:

**left-button:**

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="row_1" onclick="row_update('1_9');">
<i class="fa fa-save fa-fw button-row"></i>
</button>
```

**rigth-button:**

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="1_2_b" onclick="update('1_2_b');">
<i class="fa fa-save fa-fw"></i>
</button>
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Both of your buttons are submit buttons, so clicking the left one would submit the form it is in (if it is in a form), which might appear similar to the Ajax request in the `update()` function - is it possible that that is what's happening?

Comment: can you please post the full html content?

Comment: That was it! I deleted the form tag (I didn't want to use it, but I forgot to remove it). Thanks man! I appreciate.

Comment: Another question...how both were supposed to be submit buttons without specifying a submit attribute?

Comment: `<button>` elements that don't have a `type` specified are submit buttons by default. If you don't want that you should use `<button type="button">`. (Or if they're not in a form it doesn't matter - until you copy/paste into a form without noticing the lack of `type`...)

Answer (score 0):

you have to stop event bubbling

try this:

```
left-button:

<button class="btn btn-default" id="row_1" onclick="row_update(event,'1_9');">
<i class="fa fa-save fa-fw button-row"></i>
</button>

rigth-button:

<button class="btn btn-default" id="1_2_b" onclick="update(event,'1_2_b');">
<i class="fa fa-save fa-fw"></i>
</button>


 <script>
 function update(event,buttonid){
   document.getElementById(buttonid).disabled = true;

   event.stopPropagation();

   var textboxid = buttonid.slice(0, -2);
   var id= textboxid.substr(0, textboxid.indexOf('_'));
   var columnid= textboxid.substr(textboxid.indexOf('_')+1, textboxid.length);
   var value=document.getElementById(textboxid).value;

   var str=textboxid+"_"+value;


   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
     // code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.open("GET","ListaRyF/Update?q="+str,true);
   xmlhttp.send();

   return false;
 }


function row_update(event,buttonid)
{
 event.stopPropagation();
  /* your codes goes here */

return false;
}
 </script>
```

now they will work Separately hover ever by this way you don't need button ids
just be sure you are adding event parameter to actions